# docker --add-hosts flag equivalent in remote API?

Tags: docker

I want to use the --add-hosts flag in the docker remote API. 
https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#network-settings

```
--add-host=""    : Add a line to /etc/hosts (host:IP)
```

This is an option for `docker run` so I assumed it would be possible to pass it to /containers/create in the remote API.
https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.16/#create-a-container

Is there a remote API equivalent for this flag yet?

Comment: Found answer on IRC, pull request for docs pending:
https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/10272

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By looking in the Docker [source](https://github.com/docker/docker/commit/68e48b65a64df10fc797cbaa89d6caa2188eadc9#diff-83a075daa1f1fdbcfc9e8ff2364b0788R52), I can see it's called `ExtraHosts`.

Update: now in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.16/#create-a-container) also.

Comment: Actually I found ```ExtraHosts``` here (https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#tag/Image/operation/ImageBuild) but it is in the build phase. Is this correct? AFAIK setting hosts (```--add-host```) is in the run phase.